# Cannot connect to Eaton 9130 UPS: Unable to find POWERWARE UPS device on USB bus

Tags: ups, nut

I am trying to set up a USB connection to an Eaton 9130 UPS.

I have configured `/etc/nut/ups.conf` as such:

```
[Powerware9130]
driver = bcmxcp_usb
port = auto
```

Running `/lib/nut/bcmxcp_usb -a Powerware9130` gives this:

```
Network UPS Tools - BCMXCP UPS driver 0.28 (2.7.2)
USB communication subdriver 0.22
Unable to find POWERWARE UPS device on USB bus (USB)

Things to try:

 - Connect UPS device to USB bus

 - Run this driver as another user (upsdrvctl -u or 'user=...' in ups.conf).
   See upsdrvctl(8) and ups.conf(5).

Fatal error: unusable configuration
```

`lsusb -v` shows this:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0463:ffff MGE UPS Systems UPS
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0463 MGE UPS Systems
  idProduct          0xffff UPS
  bcdDevice            0.11
  iManufacturer           1 EATON Powerware
  iProduct                2 9130
```

I made sure that the USB device has permissions and I even tried running `bcmxcp_usb` with `-u root` to no avail.

```
$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003/004
crw-rw-r-- 1 root nut 189, 259 May  1 22:47 /dev/bus/usb/003/004
```

(And in any case, the error doesn't talk about permission issues, etc...)
Any idea what I might miss?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Might be worthwhile to try out the other driver for Eaton 9130 `usbhid-ups` as in

`/lib/nut/usbhid-ups -a Powerware9130 -DDDDD`

Also the the USB cable if it's too long can sometimes mess up the connection (I know it sounds trivial but it happened twice on my end)

Comment: Thanks.
I completely forgot about this...
I gave up eventually and hooked it via serial and it works fine...